# Can Elasticsearch be restored incrementally

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to reduce the downtime during a Elasticsearch cluster migration.
The idea is to take a snapshot (while the system is online), restore it to the new cluster, and then shut the system down, take another snapshot (this will be a smaller incremental snapshot) and then restore that snapshot to the new cluster.

The idea is that the second restoration will take less time and we can reduce the system downtime.

However, I am not able to confirm the restoration works. I get no errors when I do

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' ${ES_URL}/_snapshot/es-backup-repo-oregon/snapshot-2021-08-05/_restore -d
```

I am not able to check this at index level.

So the question is, is it possible to restore incrementally?
Is there a better way to check the restoration happened?

Thank you.

Comment: elasticsearch-dump has option offset, and scrollId might be what you are looking for? https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump

Comment: By incrementally, you mean one full index after another or a fraction of each indexes at a time?

Comment: By incremental I mean I want to restore the indexes that were added after last snapshot was taken.

Answer (score 1):

to restore a currently active index you need to remove that index from the cluster. so you can't do a partial restore of a single index, no

have you considered doing a remote reindex instead?